# remove leading characters from 12 digit numbers

Tags: sed, awk, grep

I have a text file with id and number. All numbers are expected to be 10 digits long. In the following example only the 3rd row is correct.

```
36000003326|917668001520
36000003359|919005119822
36000003417|9153914209
36000003508|919454102627
```

If the number is 12 digits long, the first 2 country digits should be removed. The expected results are as follows:

```
36000003326|7668001520
36000003359|9005119822
36000003417|9153914209
36000003508|9454102627
```

The following sed is working but it does not check if the target entry is 10 digits or 12 digits long.

```
sed 's/|91/|/'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this?

```
sed -r 's/\|..(.{10})/|\1/'
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using awk:

```
awk -F"|" 'length($2)>10{$2=substr($2,3);}1' OFS="|" file
```

Answer (score 0):

This migh work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r 's/[0-9]{2}([0-9]{10})$/\1/' file
```